# Backup wordpress site in AWS and then delete instance in EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have an old site of a company that is no longer operating. So, I'd like to delete the EC2 instance where is hosted the site and stop paying for that. But before, I'd like to make a backup of the site. It is a wordpress, installed through bitnami.

I'd like to know what is the best way yo backup the site, so I can restore it in case it is needed, for any reason.

I thought of download all the files, through Filezilla, but I think that's no good if I need to restore the site. Maybe create an image (AMI) ? And then what?

I'm just an amateur en AWS... I appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

A couple options:

- back up the website files to an S3 bucket which is very cheap (this is what I would recommend)
- another option would be to create an AMI of the instance so that you can restore it at any time in the future. This requires a snapshot to be taken of the volume on the instance so you will pay a bit more per month than with S3.